# Convertir estas apis dinamicas a estáticas C#

Tags: c#

Hola como podría pasar estas funciones a estáticas:

```
#region "Dynamic API's"

private delegate bool ReadProcessMemoryParameters(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref uint lpBuffer, uint nSize, ref uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
readonly ReadProcessMemoryParameters ReadProcessMemory = CreateApi<ReadProcessMemoryParameters>("kernel32", "ReadProcessMemory");

private delegate bool CreateProcessParameters(string ApplicationName, string CommandLine, IntPtr ProcessAttributes, IntPtr ThreadAttributes, bool InheritHandles, uint CreationFlags, IntPtr Environment, string CurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO StartupInfo, ref PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation);
CreateProcessParameters CreateProcess = CreateApi<CreateProcessParameters>("kernel32", "CreateProcessA");

private delegate uint NtQueryInformationProcessParameters(IntPtr hProcess, int ProcessInformationClass, ref PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION ProcessInformation, uint ProcessInformationLength, ref uint ReturnLength);
readonly NtQueryInformationProcessParameters NtQueryInformationProcess = CreateApi<NtQueryInformationProcessParameters>("ntdll", "NtQueryInformationProcess");

private delegate bool GetThreadContext64Parameters(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT32 lpContext);
GetThreadContext64Parameters GetThreadContext64 = null;

private delegate bool IsWow64ProcessParameters(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool Wow64Process);
readonly IsWow64ProcessParameters IsWow64Process = CreateApi<IsWow64ProcessParameters>("kernel32", "IsWow64Process");

private delegate bool WriteProcessMemoryParameters(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, ref uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
readonly WriteProcessMemoryParameters WriteProcessMemory = CreateApi<WriteProcessMemoryParameters>("kernel32", "WriteProcessMemory");

private delegate uint NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr pBaseAddress);
readonly NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters NtUnmapViewOfSection = CreateApi<NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters>("ntdll", "NtUnmapViewOfSection");

private delegate IntPtr VirtualAllocExParameters(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
readonly VirtualAllocExParameters VirtualAllocEx = CreateApi<VirtualAllocExParameters>("kernel32", "VirtualAllocEx");

private delegate uint ResumeThreadParameters(IntPtr hThread);
readonly ResumeThreadParameters ResumeThread = CreateApi<ResumeThreadParameters>("kernel32", "ResumeThread");

#endregion
```

he intentado con:

```
private static delegate
```

Con todos, pero no ha funcionado, como podría poner las funciones en estático?

Answer (score 0):

Declarar un delegado como `static` no tiene ningun sentido. La declaración de un delegado simplemente es una definición de tipo:

> Cada tipo delegado describe el número y tipo de los argumentos, así como el tipo del valor devuelto de los métodos que puede encapsular
>
> [*Tutorial de delegados,MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx)

En todo caso, si puedes declarar como `static` una instancia de tu delegado:

```
private delegate uint ResumeThreadParameters(IntPtr hThread);
static readonly ResumeThreadParameters ResumeThread = CreateApi<ResumeThreadParameters>("kernel32", "ResumeThread");
```